# ubuntu asked for reinstall in 14.04 then again asking to install

Tags: reinstall

note that: i am installing ubuntu 14.04. (I clicked erase all and install but failed first time. so clicked without booting.).

.
after installations ubuntu it failed booting. so I clicked on continue with out booting watching one of help question here. where needed to repair later. but it asked for restart. then nothing came..

.
.
( as I make changes previously to storage. and maken some problem. where my all pertition except the windows recovery  mixed uup.I uunfortunately make tthese change wwhile installing uubuntu.so booting problem in my pc. ) 
.

now installations type is now 4 type
.
1. reinstall everthing kept but system wide will cleared.
.
2.install along side ubuntu
.
3.erase ubunu and install
.
4.#something else. 
.

help me immediately. please. thank you.!

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble installing Ubuntu, have you checked that your disk/iso is functioning correctly?
Another thing you can try is to run a program like DBan or Killdisk to completely wipe the hard drive and then install Ubuntu fresh. Just curious is there a reason you are installing 14.04 instead of the newer LTS version?
If your not able to get anything to boot your safest bet might just be to wipe the hard drive and start from fresh.
If you run a live disk are you able to recover anything from the drive?

Comment: thanks. I successfully installed.I had to reinstall 2 times. then pre-installed.. I had this iso file before. that's why. no curiosity.  yes I didn't want to download new version first.